# AND-searching child objects in Lucene / Hibernate-search

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

In my web application, competence data for users can be stored with a ranking 0-5. Using Hibernate search (built on top of Lucene), I wish to construct a query that finds all users with competence X having a minimum ranking A, for example Java with ranking 3. Furthermore, I would like increased ranking to be boosted in the result, placing a user with ranking 4 before a user with ranking 3. I feel this should be possible, but I cannot figure out how to combine fields in child objects. My datastructure looks like this (simplified):

User.class

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "COMPETENCE", name = "users")
@Indexed
public class User{    
    @Id
    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.UN_TOKENIZED)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private List<UserCompetence> competenceList= new ArrayList<UserCompetence>();

    // Snip: Other irrelevant fields and get/setters

}
```

UserCompetence.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_competence")
public class Competence {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @NotNull
    @ContainedIn
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "competence_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @NotNull
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Competence competence;

    @Basic
    @Field(index = Index.UN_TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
    @NumericField
    private Integer level;

     // Snip: Other irrelevant fields and get/setters
}

@Entity()
@Table(name = "competence")
public class Competence{

    @Column(name = "name")
    @Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
    private String name;

    // Snip: Other irrelevant fields and get/setters
}
```

When I try to construct a query forcing a certain competence ANDa minimum level, it seems to find all people having that competence AND *any* competence with the specified level. How do I make it return only Users with correct UserCompetence children? I suspect I will need to remap some of my indexes to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I ended up with a custom bridge that combines the two field in one, then use phrase search to search in the combined field.

```
public class UserCompetenceBridge implements FieldBridge {
    @Override
    public void set(
            String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        UserCompetence pc = (UserCompetence ) value;

        // Add competence level + competence id combined field for specific competence querying
        String lvl = pc.getLevel() == null ? "0" : pc.getLevel().toString();
        String comp = pc.getCompetence().getId().toString();

        String fieldValue = comp + SearchFields.FIELD_SEPERATOR + lvl;
        Field compLvl = new Field(SearchFields.COMPETENCE_LEVEL, fieldValue, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
        compLvl.setBoost(luceneOptions.getBoost());
        document.add(compLvl);

        // Add competence names for free text search
        Field compName = new Field(SearchFields.COMPETENCE_NAME, pc.getCompetence().getName(), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
        document.add(compName);

    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_competence")
@ClassBridge(impl = UserCompetenceBridge.class)
public class UserCompetence {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ContainedIn
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "competence_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Competence competence;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "competence_level")
    private Integer level;
}
```

Searching for level > x like this:

```
for (CompetenceParam cp : param.getCompetences()) {
    BooleanJunction or = qb.bool();
    for(int i = cp.getMinLevel(); i <= 5 ; i++){
        or = or.should(qb.phrase()
                .onField(SearchFields.COMPETENCE_LEVEL)
                .boostedTo(1 + i/5f)
                .sentence(cp.getCompetenceId() + " " + i)
                .createQuery());
    }
    queries.add(or.createQuery());
}
```

This boosts people with high level and seems very fast.

Answer (score 2):

What you try to do is not possible with your current mapping. All the *UserCompetence* instances of the user will be indexed as part of the same user *Document*. The data gets in this case flatend. If you write the AND query, you get maybe one competence hit in one *UserCompetence* instance and one hit of minimum level in another. They belong to the same user, but are not part of the same instances of the user will be indexed as part of the same *UserCompetence* instance.

One way around would be to index *UserCompetence*. Then you can search with AND logic to match a single *UserCompetence* instance.

Comment: I tried indexing UserCompetence but the time required to rebuilding the index went from 30 seconds to almost an hour. If i went with that solution, how would searching be done? I still wish to search for User objects rather than User Competence objects. I also found the possibility of combining fields in a single index, which seems some issues in itself.

Comment: You can create an index for _User_ and _UserCompetence_ and target the right index depending on the query. How do you rebuild the index? The mass indexer can give an increased performance. Or depending on your indexing just rely on automatic indexing as part of database changes. You probably want to look at @IndexedEmbedded#depth. Depending on your object graph you might index too much. Regarding the search result. For the particular query you mentioned you would search UserCompetence instances and then navigate to the User from there.

Comment: I'm planning to use the mass indexer in a nightly job, while relying on hibernate search to update changes during the day. I don't quite like the solution of querying UserCompetence instead of User, it sounds like it could cause later trouble, and sounds like it would increase search times linearly with the number of competences and also do things with my boost/norm values. I found one solution that seems to work decent enough: using a bridge to combine competence and level in a single field, then use a phrase query to search for exact instances of competence-level.

Comment: One concern, would changes to related entities fetched from the bridge  update the index?